# I can’t configure NTP to work with the GPS module as a synchronization source (NMEA + PPS)

Tags: 18.04, ntp, gps

I can not configure NTP on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Linux 4.15.0-74-generic). As a source of synchronization I want to use NMEA + PPS from GPS module.

GPS module is connected via USB using the SILABS CP2102 interface converter:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

A PPS GPS receiver signal is connected to the DCD line of the converter. There are no problems with getting NMEA data and working with them in NTP. A problem has occurred using the PPS signal. I do ldattach PPS / dev / ttyUSB0:

```
[ 1815.641450] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[ 1815.641812] pps pps0: new PPS source usbserial2
[ 1815.641820] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyUSB0" added
```

The corresponding pps0 node appears in / dev. Everything seems to be fine, but it just doesn’t work.

```
ppswatch /dev/pps0
trying PPS source "/dev/pps0"
found PPS source "/dev/pps0"
time_pps_fetch() error -1 (Connection timed out)
time_pps_fetch() error -1 (Connection timed out)
```

Accordingly, NTP does not see the PPS signal. In the kernel, support seems to be included:

```
# HSI clients
#
CONFIG_HSI_CHAR=m
CONFIG_PPS=m
# CONFIG_PPS_DEBUG is not set

#
# PPS clients support
#
# CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_KTIMER is not set
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_LDISC=m
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_PARPORT=m
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_GPIO=m
```

pps_ldisc after ldattach loaded:

```
lsmod|grep pps
pps_ldisc              16384  1
pps_core               20480  2 pps_ldisc,ptp
```

How to find a problem? Where to looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First need to make /dev/pps0 working.
`apt install pps-tools; ppstest /dev/pps0`
if it is not working.
make sure that /dev/pps0 is using proper source: `dmesg | grep pps`

```
[    5.358856] pps pps0: new PPS source pps.-1
[    5.358947] pps pps0: Registered IRQ 349 as PPS source
```

ntp's nmea driver requires
"/dev/gps%d"    /* GPS serial device */
"/dev/gpspps%d" /* PPSAPI device override */ -> symlink to /dev/pps0

Also make sure that you use correct settings in ntp.conf
e.g.
[https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/drivers/driver20.html](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/drivers/driver20.html)
`server 127.127.20.0 mode 88 maxpoll 1 prefer true fudge 127.127.20.0 time1 0 flag1 1 refid GPS`

where mode 88
linespeed 115200 bps and process $GPZDA or $GPZDG